# Javascript Regex to allow only 2 digit numbers and 3 digit numbers as comma separated

Tags: javascript, regex

I want Regex for Javascript for below validation:

Textbox should allow only 2 digit numbers and 3 digit numbers as comma separated.
Ex: 12,123,56,567,789,11

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Hey welcome to Stackoverflow,

try this one

- `([0-9]{1,3},)*` - last two or three digit should be **without** comma
- `(\d{1,3},)*$` - last two or three digit **should have** comma
- `(\d{2,3}),?` - **captures both case** - wether last two digit have comma or not

You can test regular expressions online in [this website](https://regex101.com/) - make sure the javascript is selected

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression instead `/([0-9]{2,3}),?/gi`

This will capture any 2 or 3 digit numbers, without the optional `,` separator.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Regex too.

```
[0-9]{2,3}[,]{0,1}
```

https://regexr.com/452l2

Answer (score 0):

```
^               # beginning of line
  \d{2,3}       # 2 or 3 digits
  (?:           # start non capture group
    ,           # a comma
    \d{2,3}     # 2 or 3 digits
  )*            # end group may appear 0 or more times
$               # end of line
```

If you don't want numbers that start with `0` like `025`

```
^               # beginning of line
  [1-9]         # digit fomr 1 to 9
  \d            # 1 digit
  \d?           # 1 optional digit
  (?:           # start non capture group
    ,           # a comma
    [1-9]       # digit fomr 1 to 9
    \d          # 1 digit
    \d?         # 1 optional digit
  )*            # end group may appear 0 or more times
$               # end of line
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/EIXVbS/1)

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match all your cases: `^(?:\d{2,3},)+(\d{2,3}),?$|^\d{2,3}$`

https://regex101.com/r/CdYVi9/2

Sample JS:

```
const isValid = str => /^(?:\d{2,3},)+(\d{2,3}),?$|^\d{2,3}$/.test(str);
```